# Invalid byte sequence using HTML sanitizer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8, html-sanitizing

I ran to this error using Rails `HTML::FullSanitizer`on rails console:

```
h = HTML::FullSanitizer.new
html = "Something with invalid characters \x80 and tags ī."
h.sanitze html

ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
from /Users/benaluan/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/vendor/html-scanner/html/sanitizer.rb:37:in `sanitize'
```

What I tried is to encode the html before sanitizing:

```
html = html.encode('UTF-8', 'binary', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
```

It works, however, it removes the **ī** character. Does anyone experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this article which describes exactly your problem: http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/7/7/stripping-invalid-utf-8/

A code of a solution from this article:

```
html = html.force_encoding('UTF-8').
      encode('UTF-16', :invalid => :replace, :replace => '').
      encode('UTF-8')
```